# How to find smart contract adress and hash code in Etherscan

Tags: hash, blockchain, ethereum, etherscan

I want to find a smart contract address and a hash code on the Ethereum blockchain using Etherscan.

I clicked some random transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf39612cbe8ddacdb00b81fa863fc11cbb5194233c50ddaab1a402dc092f7259d
But I don't know if its hash code on Ethereum blockchain. Can you answer, how can I be sure about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the smart contract address by looking at the field "Interacted With (To)". Here you have the clickable hash code of the contract.

In your example, it looks as follows

[image]

Then, you can follow the contract link to find more details. In your case it's https://etherscan.io/address/0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b#code

[image]